# Excel to use external link in a variable format

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large data set of files that have to constantly be updated via a heavy VBA script, i would like to separate it out so that the VBA script is by itself 1 file and the data files can be separated into smaller chunks.

Hence i wanted to link my data from my data file into my VBA file in a manner of external reference as so :

```
 =[DATA.xlsm]Crays!E12
```

but i have a few DATA.xlsm, and would like it to change as i can select/key in the value rather than having it constant, so say if i want DATA2 table to be loaded, i just key in DATA2 in say the cell E9, then the value of it can be automatically changed into

```
 =[DATA2.xlsm]Crays!E12
```

I am looking into something more like

```
 =['E9'.xlsm]Crays!E12
```

but am not sure if this is possible or if there's a way to make it possible?

Comment: see [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) ... or if building the path through VBA, use `sFormula = "[" & Range("E9").Value & ".xlsm]Crays!E12"`

Comment: perhaps better [indirect](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html) example